# Receiving Outlook attachment name into C# datagrid

Tags: c#, datagridview, outlook, attachment

currently my application is pulling in all unread emails from my Outlook and displaying them in the datagridview. What is causing me a boat load of stress is the error: "System.__ComObject" that is showing up in the "Attachment" column.

All I'm trying to do is get the attachment names from unread Outlook emails into the attachment column.

I don't understand where I'm going wrong. Any help would be great.

Thank you.

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

try
        {
            Outlook._Application app = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.NameSpace ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            Outlook.Items UnRead = inbox.Items.Restrict("[Unread]=true");

            ns.SendAndReceive(true);

            dt = new DataTable("Inbox");
            dt.Columns.Add("From Email", typeof(String));
            dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(String));
            dt.Columns.Add("Subject", typeof(String));
            dt.Columns.Add("Body", typeof(String));
            dt.Columns.Add("Attachments", typeof(String));
            dt.Columns.Add("Print Body", typeof(String));
            dt.Columns.Add("File Format", typeof(String));
            dt.Columns.Add("Selected", typeof(String));

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            foreach (Object item in inbox.Items)
            {
                if ((item as Outlook.MailItem) != null && (item as Outlook.MailItem).UnRead == true)
                {
                    Outlook.MailItem item1 = (Outlook.MailItem)item;

        dt.Rows.Add(new Object[] { item1.SenderName, item1.SentOn.ToLongDateString() + "" + item1.SentOn.ToLongTimeString(), item1.Subject,
        item1.Body, item1.Attachments});
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Retrieving Unread Email Messages.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Well obviously `Attachments` is a **collection** of items, so can either just pick the first attached item (if one exists) and display its name or you need to handle a list of attached items. Using the debugger and inspecting `item1.Attachments` would be a good first stop.

Comment: I think I have the code to list the attachments, but I'm not sure where to insert it.

Comment: If you have working code for creating a list of attachment names, just place it before `dt.Rows.Add(...)` and replace `item1Attachments` with the variable holding your list of attachment names.

Comment: 'private void GetAttachments(Outlook.MailItem mailitem)
        {
            Outlook.Attachments attachments = mailitem.Attachments;
            if (attachments != null && attachments.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= attachments.Count; i++)
                {
                    Outlook.Attachment attachment = attachments[i];
                    if (attachment.Type == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }'